# JFrog CLI search with json filespec ignoring the include?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I'm using the below json filespec for a search query with Jfrog CLI but it's ignoring the "include" part of the spec. There's no documentation on using include within a filespec, just straight AQL examples.

```
{
    "files": [{
        "aql": {
            "items.find":{
                "$and" : [
                    {"created" : {"$before" : "1y"}},
                    {"repo" : {"$match":"docker-local"}},
                    {"stat.downloads":{"$eq":null}},
                    {"name" : { "$nmatch" : "sha256*" }}
                ]
            }
        },
        "sortBy":["created"],
        "include":["path","name","created_by"]
    }]
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's ignoring anything not in the "aql" object. I added a bunch of random entries like `"foo":"bar"` under `include` and `sortBy` and no error was thrown, nor was it acknowledged in anyway.
My question is, where does the include fit into the spec.json file?

Comment: Related 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062970/how-to-change-the-include-section-of-an-aql-query-in-a-file-spec

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246409/artifactory-aql-in-jfrog-rt-search-include-fields

Comment: Judging from the filespec [schema](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/blob/v2/schema/filespec-schema.json?), it looks like it unfortunately doesn't fit anywhere. There is also an option for "--include" to go along with the search command but it doesn't seem to do anything when using a spec. Additionally, some arguments will cause a message "Error No arguments should be sent when the spec option is used".